# Bash script automation issue

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm taking this out of context but this bit of my script doesn't execute properly:

```
latest=$(ls ~/Videos/ -t | head -n 1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
mpv ~/Videos/$latest
```

I'm trying to automatically play the latest file added to my Videos directory. The following error occurs:

```
Error parsing option t (option not found)
Setting command line option '--t=' failed.

Exiting... (Fatal error)
```

Comment: try this `latest=$(ls -t ~/Videos/  | head -n 1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g')`.

Comment: I think it would be better to forget about sed and simply *quote the variable* to prevent word splitting i.e. `latest=$(ls -t -- ~/Videos/ | head -n 1)` then `mpv "$latest"`

Comment: or in one single command  `mpv ~/Videos/$(ls -t ~/Videos/  | head -n 1)`

Comment: Are you *really sure* that the two lines above cause the error you describe? I can not reproduce it and don't think that this is the correct snippet.

Comment: @ByteCommander the only thing I can think is that the error is from `mpv`, and it's due to a filename that includes a string starting with `--t`. I'm not familiar with `mpv` so I don't know if it supports a GNU-style `--` to indicate the end of options - if it does, that might be helpful i.e. `mpv -- "$latest"`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of `ls` is [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Doing so when that output is a list of video files is an absolutely horrible idea. Video files will almost certainly contain spaces and other strange characters which are very likely to cause problems. Here's a safer alternative that does the same thing:

```
latest="$(stat --printf '%Y\t%n\0' * | sort -zk1 | tail -zn1 | cut -f2-)"
mpv "$latest"
```

Or, if your `tail` doesn't have the `-z` flag:

```
latest="$(stat --printf '%Y\t%n\0' * | sort -rzk1 | awk -F'\t' -vRS='\0' '{print $2; exit}'
```

Or

```
latest="$(stat --printf '%Y\t%n\0' * | sort -rzk1 | perl -00pe 's/^\d+\s+(.*?)\0.*/$1/s')"
```

Note the quoting. You should [*always* quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222) unless you are absolutely certain that quoting will break something. This solution uses `stat` to print the modification date of the file (`%Y`), a tab (`\t`), the file's name (`%n`) and a NULL character (`\0`). This is fed to sort which sorts on the 1st field (`-k1`), the date and expects null-separated input (`-z`). It is then passed through `tail` to get the last (`-n1`) null-separated (`-z`) line and, finally, `cut` removes the date leaving only the file name. This ensures that you can deal with arbitrary files, even any with newlines in their names.

---

The error you are seeing is hard to diagnose without knowing the names of the files in `~/Videos`. The main issue is that you're not quoting the variable's name, and since there seems to be a file with `--t`, that is taken as an argument. If you know your file names will never contain newlines, you could also do:

```
latest="$(ls ~/Videos/ -t | head -n 1)"
mpv ~/Videos/"$latest"
```

But this is really a bad habit to get into and should never be used in production code.

Comment: ummm....`tail` does not have a `-z` option to read null-separated input..

Comment: @heemayl You're right. This is the same thing, but will not work properly with files that have newlines in the name: `stat --printf '%Y\t%n\n' * | sort -k1 | tail -n 1 | cut -f2-`

Comment: @heemayl ah, OK. Mine does but it might be a newer version. I'll add a different approach tomorrow.

Comment: @terdon The simplest solution might be to just error if there are any filenames with newlines, like so:  `if [[ "$(echo * | wc -l)" -ne 1 ]]; then echo "Newline present. Aborting..."; exit 1; fi` Newlines can mess up other scripts, so personally, I would avoid putting them in filenames altogether.

Comment: @wjandrea of course, we all avoid putting them in file names but we often don't control the input our scripts are given so it's a good idea to be ready for them. Modern versions of GNU `tail` have `-z` so my first solution will work but I also added two other ones, all of which can deal wit arbitrary file names.